# Using axioms for deductions in z3

Tags: c#, z3

I am a new user to Z3 and want it to use some axioms and only those axioms to reduce a formula to another equivalent formula in first order logic.
Ex:
  Use only

1.(p or q) and (p or r) <=> p or (r and q)

2.not(p or q) <=> not(p) and not(q)

3.p and p <=> p

to prove

not(p or (q and r)) <=> (not(p)and not(q)) or (not(p)and not(r))

I use the C# API.
 I guess it has to use uninterpreted function but I have no idea how to do so.

Plzz Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, the idea is to use uninterpreted functions and sorts.
Here is the problem encoded in Z3:
http://rise4fun.com/Z3/Vzns

Z3 does not find a proof using the 3 axioms you provided.
Actually, the conclusion does not follow from them.
However, it can find a proof if we replace the axiom

> p and p <=> p

with

> not(not(p)) <=> p

Remark: the encoding in the script above uses uninterpreted sort `B` instead of `Bool`. Thus, Z3 will also not try a proof by case analysis nor will try to use the fact that `Bool` contains only two elements.

Remark: it uses `=` instead of `<=>`.

In the following example, we use Z3Py to construct a model that satisfies the 3 axioms you provided, but the conjecture does not hold.

http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/7H7

Comment: I earlier was using context.ParseSmtLib(Args) to convert a logical formula input by the user in SMT-LIB format as a string to get it converted into a valid Term and then assert the formula.
I still want the user to input the formula as a string or in any other possible way . How do i then process it to get a valid Term which is formula in the newly created sort. 

P.S. I use the C# API.
Thanks.

Comment: The .NET API in Z3 4.0 has methods called `ParseSMTLIB2String` and `ParseSMTLIB2String`. Both of them allows us to "bind" symbols (sort names) with sorts. That is, we can initialize the parser symbol table with a sort created using the API. The Z3 4.0 distribution contains an example (file `test_managed.cs`, method `assert_comm_axiom`) that shows how to do it. The example uses `ParseSMTLIBString`. The function `ParseSMTLIB2String` is similar but expects SMT 2.0 syntax instead of SMT 1.0.

Comment: Hi! If I try inserting the axiom (q->r)->(pVq)->(pVr) then using z3.MkImplies does not work,it gives an error at runtime. If i use an uninterpreted function (implies (B) B) then I too I get an error. And in uninterpreted function it is not used as desired. I have to use it as implies(q)=pVq. Please help me with this!!

Comment: Could you post the script that produces the error? You can try it using rise4fun.com, and then create a permalink.

Comment: If you want a `rewrite-like` proof, you can create the uninterpreted symbol `IMPLIES`, and add the axiom stating that `(IMPLIES A B)` is equal to `(OR (NOT A) B)`. If you want the logical implication semantics, you can define the sort `B` as `(define-sort B () Bool)`. That is, it is an alias for `Bool`. It will allow you to write axioms such as `(implies q (OR p q))`. There are many options. The ideal option depends on what is your goal.